# Android Drag and Drop Custom tree node in a Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, android-custom-view

I want to show the hierarchy tree view From a custom List view in to the `RecyclerView` (As looks in below Image).The node can be drag and drop in to any position. Please give me guide line foe how to start this?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443314/android-custom-drag-and-drop-node-tree-in-a-recyclerview

Comment: @MikeM.this is same question but there is no answer

Comment: Yes, you repeated that question here. Don't do that.

Comment: It is your question, verbatim, with the [exact same image](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50443314/edit) (accidentally hidden with a bad edit). It's just on a different account. Don't do that.